# Group By in sql subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

So i have a query where i am trying to accumulate the count of order for phone and website however i realise you cant use a GROUP BY clause in the subquery when it is directly within a select as it returns more than one value. Therefore my question is where do i put the subquerys to achieve the same result.

```
SELECT CAST(a.DateCreated AS DATE), 
        (SELECT count(CAST(DateCreated AS DATE))
         FROM [Sterlingbuild].[dbo].[CustomerOrder]
         WHERE BookingSourceId = 1
         GROUP BY CAST(DateCreated AS DATE)) AS 'Website',
         (SELECT count(CAST(DateCreated AS DATE))
         FROM [Sterlingbuild].[dbo].[CustomerOrder]
         WHERE BookingSourceId = 2
         GROUP BY CAST(DateCreated AS DATE)) AS 'Phone'
  , count(CAST(a.DateCreated AS DATE)) AS 'Total Orders'
  FROM [Sterlingbuild].[dbo].[CustomerOrder] a
  WHERE CustomerOrderStatusId = 7
  AND DepartmentId = 1
  GROUP BY CAST(a.DateCreated AS DATE)
  ORDER BY CAST(a.DateCreated AS DATE)
```

When i run this query it works therefore i know the data is correct:

```
  SELECT count(CAST(DateCreated AS DATE))
     FROM [Sterlingbuild].[dbo].[CustomerOrder]
     WHERE BookingSourceId = 1
     AND CustomerOrderStatusId = 7 AND DepartmentId = 1
     GROUP BY CAST(DateCreated AS DATE)
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT CAST(co.DateCreated AS DATE), 
       SUM(CASE WHEN BookingSOurceId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Website,
       SUM(CASE WHEN BookingSOurceId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Phone,
       COUNT(*) as Total_Orders
FROM [Sterlingbuild].[dbo].[CustomerOrder] co
WHERE CustomerOrderStatusId = 7 AND DepartmentId = 1
GROUP BY CAST(a.DateCreated AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(a.DateCreated AS DATE)
```